# Handling struct returned from c++ called from python

Tags: python, ctypes

I'd like to use a function that is defined in a DLL from Python.
The value returned from the C++ function (get_version) is a struct

```c
typedef struct myStruct {
    size_t size;
    char * buff;
} myStruct ;
```

The Python code is:

```
lib = CDLL(myDLL.dll)
lib.get_version
```

The question is how do I handle the returned value?

I've read Voo's answer and reading other posts, but I'm still struggling with this

I declared the struct class (Foo, from Voo's answer) and set the `restype`
The code now looks

```
class Foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('size', c_size_t), ('buff', c_char_p)]

lib = CDLL(myDLL.dll)
lib.get_version
lib.get_version.restype = Foo._fields_
```

I get the following error
**TypeError: restype must be a type, a callable, or None**

I read about this and if I set the `restype` not as a list, e.g.: c_char_p, the error doesn't appear

When I set the `restype`

lib.restype = Foo.*fields*

The error doesn't appear but the `restype` for `get_version` is not set correctly
When looking at the variables in debug:

lib.restype = list: [('size', ), ('buff', )]

lib.get_version.restype = PyCSimpleType:

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `ctypes` works with C functions, so if using C++ make sure to `extern "C"` the function.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me please what is return type of function in dll?
I've tried with my myStruct but get error: `C linkage function cannot return C++ class 'myStruct '`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use the [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) module. You'll just have to define the struct in your python code with ctypes.

Something like:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class Foo(Structure):
...     _fields_ = [("size", c_size_t), ("buff", c_char_p)]
```

should do the trick. Then you just set the `restype` of your `get_version` method to your struct so that the interpreter knows what it does return and then you can use it as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I read other posts on the issue but I'm still  struggling with this. I've add more information on the original question

Comment: @user1478497 You have to set the `restype` value of the method *not* the whole dll. Also you shouldn't point it to `_fields_` but the struct itself, i.e. `lib.get_version.restype = Foo`. Finally you probably should use a better name than foo ;)